# Show entered password with geli

Tags: freebsd, bsd, disk-encryption

In FreeBSD you get access to a geli-encrypted partition by:

```
geli attach -k /root/ada1.key /dev/ada1
```

Which then opens a password prompt. Is there a way to get the password displayed while it is entered?

Comment: Are you looking for the `-d` option, which was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/53bbe84593128de307889556721013510572c06e)?